# How can I make this figure fit on the page, without going over the margin?

Tags: tikz-trees, graphs, automata

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
            chains,
            fit,
            positioning,
            quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
start chain = going right,
arr/.style = {draw, semithick, rounded    corners, -Straight Barb},
 N/.style = {circle, draw, fill=none, minimum size=1em, 
             outer sep=3pt, font=\tiny},
EN/.style = {N, double, double    distance=1.5pt},
 every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
                ]
% position the nodes a...c
\coordinate[label=left:I] (a);
\node (novoInicial) [N, right=of a] {$q_1$};
\node (b) [N, right=of novoInicial] {$q_2$};
\node (c) [N, above right=of b] {$q_3$};
% position the nodes 8...12
  \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
    \node (d) [N, below right=of c] {$q_8$};
    \foreach \i in {9, 10,...,12}{
        \node (\i) [N] {$q_{\i}$};
    }
\end{scope}
\node (ei) [EN, right=of 12] {$q_{13}$};
\path   
(a) edge (novoInicial)
(novoInicial) edge["$\varepsilon$"] (b)
(b) edge["$\varepsilon$"] (c)
(c) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (d)
(d) edge["0"]               (9)
(9) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (10)
(10) edge["0"]               (11)
(11) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (12)
(12) edge["1"]               (ei)
;
\draw[arr]  (ei) |- ([yshift=45mm] b.north west)
 to ["$\varepsilon$" '] (b.north west);
 %%%%
 \node (j) [N, above right=of c]   {$q_4$};
 \node (k) [N, right=of j] {$q_5$};
 \node (l) [N, right=of k] {$q_6$};
 \node (em) [EN, right=of l] {$q_7$};
 \path   (c) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (j)
    (j) edge["1"]               (k)
    (k) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (l)
    (l) edge["0"]               (em);
    \draw[arr]  (em) |- ([yshift=42mm] b.north)
             to ["$\varepsilon$"] (b);
     %%%%
\begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
 \node (n) [N, below right=of b] {$q_{14}$};
 \foreach \i in {15, 16,...,18}{
  \node (\i) [N] {$q_{\i}$};
  }
 \end{scope}
  \node (es) [EN, right=of 18] {$q_{19}$};
  \path (b) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (n)
    (n) edge["0"]               (15)
    (15) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (16)
    (16) edge["1"]               (17)
    (17) edge["$\varepsilon$"]   (18)
    (18) edge["0"]               (es);
  \draw[arr]  (es) |- ([yshift=-22mm] b.south) to ["$\varepsilon$"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does fit with `\usepackage[paper=a3paper]{geometry}`.

Comment: @frougon Using this command, it is no longer possible to print the document on A4 paper, right?

Comment: Use the `landscape` environment.

Comment: @B612 It is, using e.g. `pdfjam --paper a4paper --outfile out.pdf -- in.pdf` as a first step. But my comment was to be taken as a joke: your example is very far from minimal; if you're capable of creating such a complex picture, you can certainly modify its layout so that it spreads more in the vertical direction than horizontal, or use the `scale` option of the `tikzpicture` environment (and/or `x=...`, `y=...`) , or switch to landscape as @Bernard said... You need to have an idea *yourself* how you want the figure to look, we can't guess!

Comment: Another option is to reduce the distance between the nodes, for example: `node distance = 7mm and 7mm`.

Comment: It's also possible to play with `font` and`node font`.

Comment: If you don’t want to change the structure of that graph, or mess with the code, you could try using one of the boxes to scale, resize or rotate it, hence scalebox, resizebox, and rotatebox, respectively. Be artful with the font, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #1:** Decrease the margins

Suggested replacement of Line 2:

> \usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

This shrinks the margins of the page on the left and right, making more space for your picture.

**Solution #2:** Shrink the picture

As suggested by a previous commenter, you could replace Line 13 with something like

> node distance = 5mm and 5mm,

Even dropping these numbers from 12 to 10 makes a difference in spacing.

These solutions could also be used in combination with each other.